# setValue function executes, but values not updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have a user interface that toggles a status column between "Open" and "Closed."  The user interface is on a separate tab from the form data and it executes successfully, but the data is not updated.  I am using VLOOKUPs on the "Portal" sheet for user display and "Form Responses 1" as original entries from a Google Form.

I found another post that indicated to try `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`, but it either did not work or I did not employ it correctly.

```
function openCloseCell()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Portal");
  var data = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var last =s1.getLastRow();
  var valB= s2.getRange("C4").getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    var row = data[i]
    var cell = row[26]
{

if (cell == "Closed" && row[0] == valB)
{cell.setValue("Open");
}
else if (cell == "Open" && row[0] == valB)
{cell.setValue("Closed");
}
// SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
```

Comment: You're not initializing your `for` loop properly, move the curly bracket opening the `for` loop to the same line instead of defining variables in between.

Comment: Thanks, Ross.  I changed the sequence and am getting the same result.  I was thinking about each step and I had not mentioned that the value 'valB' is matching back to an arrayformula generated value...could this be the reason?

=arrayformula( if( len(B2:B), "" & text(row(B2:B) - row(B2) + 2, "000") & RIGHT(VALUE(B2:B), 3), iferror(1/0) ) )

Comment: Update- I made a silly error and was referring to the wrong column:
    var cell = row[26]

Comment: var cell  is not a range.  So it has no setValue() method.`if (cell == "Closed" && row[0] == valB)
{cell.setValue("Open");
}
else if (cell == "Open" && row[0] == valB)
{cell.setValue("Closed");
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function openCloseCell()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Portal");
  var data = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var last =s1.getLastRow();
  var valB= s2.getRange("C4").getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i]
    var cell = row[26]
    if (cell == "Closed" && row[0] == valB)
    {s1.getRange(i+1,27).setValue("Open");
    }
    else if (cell == "Open" && row[0] == valB)
    {s1.getRange(i+1,27).setValue("Closed");
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```